# rsync over ssh to esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi, rsync

I try to backup esxi via rsync over ssh.
I run rsyc but I get error:

```
# rsync -e ssh -av root@ip.esxi:file.txt .
sh: rsync: not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(635) [receiver=3.0.3]
```

If I connect with ssh/scp everything is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `rsync` on your ESXi. You can get a binary [here](http://damiendebin.net/blog/2013/12/06/esxi-5-dot-1-and-rsync/).

Comment: The site reqiure username & password.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in the URL.

Answer (score 8):

The `rsync` command is not part of the default ESXi installation. ESXi uses a modified version of [**Busybox**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox#Commands) to provide a limited subset of Linux commands on the console. That's why `rsync` isn't available. While it's *possible* to [dump a statically-compiled rsync binary](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=esxi%20rsync&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) onto an ESXi host, this is not the way to handle backups with VMware.

You can use `scp`, however.

There are better tools for VMware backups and handling virtual machines, though.

Answer (score 6):

rsync is not installed, or not installed in a location that is in your $PATH on the remote side

Comment: I not run rsync on esxi but linux server. The remote server (esxi in this case) not need installed rsync but ssh only.

Comment: yes, it has to be installed on both machines.

Answer (score 2):

why not mount esxi file systems on a third machine with sshfs and rsync support, like so:

```
#mount src esxi file system
sshfs root@aaa.bbb.ccc:/vmfs/volumes/ mnt/sshfs/
src="mnt/sshfs/"
vmd="Storage_vmfs5/vm1-data"
#mount dst esxi file system
sshfs root@xxx.yyy.zzz:/datastore-vms/ mnt/tmp/
dst="mnt/tmp/"
#copy vm files
rsync -av --progress --stats --delete --force "$src$vmd" "$dst"
#unmount
fusermount -u $src; fusermount -u $dst
```